# UnityPlayer_UAP_ARM64_release_il2cpp.pdb not loaded

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

I've installed several packages in a Unity (2020) app I'm building.   Namely: World Locking Tools, MRTK, PUN2.  World Locking Tools provides some examples that are built with assemblies defining [scripting symbols](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) that any derived files I want to build would need access to.  I'd like to create my own version of certain files from one of these examples.  To do this and have access to the scripting symbols in one of those examples, I created an assembly reference to reference the assembly for that example code within World Locking Tools package installed in my project space.  In so doing, I kept running into the common "...not found, are you missing an assembly reference" issue, which ultimately led me to creating assembly references for many of the assemblies provided by the various packages I needed to use (not just the particular example code I initially wanted to modify).  Once my project finally built successfully in unity, I then tried to upload to a Hololens 2 headset in Visual Studio.  This provided the error in the title of this post.  Coincidentally, the app also appears to fail to start on the headset.  Before I tried to alter my codebase with modified versions of files from that World Locking Tools example and with assembly references, the code would successfully build in Unity and successfully deploy to the Hololens 2 headset.

Does the behavior and missing .pdb error I describe mean that I'm missing assembly references for yet other packages even though Unity successfully builds the project?

This is my first foray into using assemblies so be please be gentle :)

Answer (score 0):

For the .pdb message, that one is ignorable since will not have that symbol available.   However, the app not starting is definitely likely due to a missing component or loading issue. When ran in debugger, may get a better idea on what is missing or from a debugger log in Unity.

Comment: I believe I tried to start the debugger by choosing `Debug -> Start Debugging` within Visual Studio but it just hung without giving errors or much output at all.